# Console login enter repeats after entering username

Tags: linux, keyboard, console

I've been a long time Linux user and today I've come across a problem that just baffles me! This is happening on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS fresh install for my nephew, I'm a long time Gentoo user myself and generally a console ninja.

My first habit on Linux issues is to switch to a console, login and do my thing from there. But magically after typing my username and hitting return the return key seems to be "stuck" and it obviously fails to login.

The weird thing is that I can unplug the keyboard and it continues to "press" return...

Pressing CTRL+C to refresh the login fixes it, until I press some characters and press return again.

This does not happen when I just press return without entering any characters.

And I can reproduce it by SSHing into the box, enabling GPM, copy some characters and then copy a line ending!

I tried different USB/PS2 keyboards and mice.

And the worst thing yet, this only applies to my console. I boot a rescue disk, works fine. I boot Windows, works fine, I boot FreeDOS, works fine. I boot normally into SDDM or any other window manager... works fine!

In my 20+ years of Linux use this is the first time I can not use a normal console... has anyone got any ideas?

(I'm trying a re-install while I write this)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499554/why-does-agetty-fail-to-determine-passwordon-ubuntu-18-04-1

Comment: Thanks, but a better explanation is found at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873

Comment: … and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500545/, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498757 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499062 , and …